# Classification of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I am trying to understand how to classify quadratic forms and I have picked the following example: trying to classify $2x^2+2y^2+5xy-4x+y-6=0$.

What I have done:

I have considered the part $2x^2+2y^2+5xy=0$ with associated matrix
$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & \frac{9}{2} \\
\frac{5}{2} & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$
with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\frac{9}{2},\ \lambda_2 =-\frac{1}{2}$ and corresponding eigenvectors $\vec{v}_{\lambda_1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2
         \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{v}_{\lambda_1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           -1
         \end{bmatrix}$. This allows us to diagonalize $A$ and write the quadratic in the form $\frac{9}{2}(x')^2-\frac{1}{2}(y')^2=0$ in the new basis, which is a pair of intersecting lines.

My question is: how do I deal with the terms $-4x+y-6$?

Thank you very much.

---

UPDATE (SOLVED): this is the equation of a conic with a mixed term $xy$ which implies it has been rotated by an angle $\tan (2\theta)=\frac{5}{2-2}=\infty\Rightarrow 2\theta =\frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow \theta =\frac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow$ we can eliminate the mixed term with the rotation $$x=X\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-Y\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}, y=X\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+Y\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}$$ so the equation $2x^2+2y^2+5xy-4x+y-6=0$ becomes
\begin{align*}
&2\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+5\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+2\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2-4\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\ &+\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-6=\frac{9}{2}X^2-\frac{1}{2}Y^2-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}X+\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}Y-6=0
\end{align*}
and by completing the square we find $\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}X-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Y-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2=0\Rightarrow$ the conic represents the pair of intersecting lines $Y=3X+2\sqrt{2}, Y =-3X+3\sqrt{2}$ in the new reference frame $(X,Y)$ and by using $X=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}, Y=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}$ we get the equation of the lines in the original reference frame $(x,y)$: $\fbox{$y=-2-2x$ and $y=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$}$.

Comment: you introduce a new variable, might as well call it $z$ and make the homogeneous form $2x^2 + 2 y^2 + 5xy -4zx +yz - 6 z^2.$

Comment: As the ternary quadratic form has discriminant $0,$  it factors, at least over the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: your expression is

$$  (x+2y-3)(2x+y+2)  .$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 5 &  - 4 \\ 
5 & 4 & 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 5 &  - 4 \\ 
5 & 4 & 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

The expression $Q^T DQ = H ,$  where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of second partials, tells us that twice your quadratic expression is
$$ 4 (x+ \frac{5}{4}y - 1)^2  - \frac{9}{4} (y- \frac{8}{3})^2  $$
where the third row has a coefficient $0.$ This is because of the $0$ diagonal element in $D.$  The result is that, being evidently a difference of squares, **twice your expression factors, and the zero set is two lines.**

Wrote it out, twice your expression is
$$  (2x+4y-6)(2x+y+2)  ,$$
so the expression not doubled is
$$  (x+2y-3)(2x+y+2)  .$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 5 &  - 4 \\ 
5 & 4 & 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 5 &  - 4 \\ 
5 & 4 & 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 6 \\ 
 - 4 & 6 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 6 \\ 
0 & 6 &  - 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 5 &  - 4 \\ 
5 & 4 & 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 5 &  - 4 \\ 
5 & 4 & 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question; sadly, I don't understand what you have done so I hope you don't mind if I ask you a few questions. It seems to me that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}4 & 5 & -4\\
5 & 4 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 & -12
\end{bmatrix}$ is $2\cdot$ the matrix of coefficients associated with the "new" quadratic form that you suggested with the $z$ variable added but I don't see: 1) why you doubled the entries of the matrix of coefficients and 2) how you have found the other two matrices that you multiply it with so could you please explain that to me if you don't mind? Thank you.

Comment: @lorenzo I doubled the entries to get a matrix of integers; also, it really is the Hessian matrix, and a quadratic form is given by $\frac{1}{2} v^T H v, $  where $v$ is a column vector of the variables.  I can paste in the calculation. At the same time, one may simply check that the determinant of $H$ is zero,  so the original polyno0mial factors.